# 外国のセキュリティポリシーの一文について

Tags: security, 英語

セキュリティポリシーでよく外国のサイトで見られるのが以下のコメントです。

> industry standard technical and organizational security measures

参考URL；https://instagantt.com/privacy.html

具体的にどのようなセキュリティをしているのかが分からないので、そのアプリを使用していいのか迷っています。
「SSLを使っています」などなら分かりやすいのですが。

上記わかる方がいましたら、ご教授願います。

Comment: 何を質問されているのかわかりません。英文の意味でしょうか？

Comment: 資料などないので上記の文言のなんとなくな理解なのですが、XSS、CSRF、クリックジャッキング、インジェクション攻撃などのよくある脆弱性を指して対策していること、SSLなどで通信を暗号化していること、など一般的に対策しているであろうことをまとめて対策していることだと認識しています。

Comment: [このAPI](https://www.instagantt.com/)？の使用を検討しているがセキュリティポリシーに不安があるのでどういった対策をしているのか知りたい。というのが質問の内容と思いますが、認識のズレもありますでしょうし標準のセキュリティ対策に不安があるのならTwitterやメールアドレスも書いてあるので直接尋ねるのも１つの手かと思います。

Comment: @suzukis 返事が遅れて申し訳ありません。英文というより、英文の内容です。「産業標準技術と組織的な安全基準」日本語に訳すとこのようになりますが、これは具体的に何をしているのかが不明だったので質問させていただきました。

Comment: @Myaku その通りです。「産業標準技術と組織的な安全基準」といえばこれ、という標準の規格があるのかと思い質問いたしました。しかし、それがよくわからないので、直接聞くのがいいですね。そうします。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Myaku アドバイスありがとうございます。なんとなくそうだと思うのですが、それが明確になっていないので気になりました。調べても具体的なものや一般的な基準はないようなので、直接会社に聞くことにします。

Comment: @kazuhiro もし、先方より返信をいただき結論が出ましたら、是非自己回答を行なって後日承認していただければと思います。